# Como chamar informações em um html de uma página .jsp

Tags: javascript, java, html5, ajax, apache-cordova

Estou desenvolvendo um app mobile Hibrido bom HTML5 e meu *backend* será feito com Java e MySQL.

Estou utilizando o PhoneGap e o mesmo para gerar o APP precisa que meus arquivos sejam de extensão `.html` `.css` `.js`, para gerar o arquivo de instalação, com isso minhas regras de negócio estão no *backend* em páginas `.jsp` que se conectam com o banco da dados. A dúvida é o seguinte como fazer com que o resultado obtido em uma página no *backend* Ex: `resultado.jsp` apareça em uma página com extensão HTML EX: `mostra-resultado.html`.

Sei que conseguiria fazer algo com Ajax mas ainda não consigo visualizar a construção disso, alguém consegue me dar uma luz ou um exemplo.

Segue mais ou menos a ideia, isso aqui é só para da uma luz ao conceito, não tem compromisso com a verdade.

```
<!--Exemplo da página html-->
<html>
    <button>Chama a lista 1</button>
    <button>Chama a lista 2</button>
    <div>
        <!--Resultado da lista que foi verificada na página.jsp-->
    </div>
</html>


<!--Exemplo da página .jsp-->
<jsp>
    if(lista1){
    <!--Mostra o resultado da lista 1 -->
    }else if(lista2){
    <!--Mostra o resultado da lista 1 -->
    }
</jsp>
```

Comment: Pelo jeito não entendi sua pergunta. Também não entendi sua réplica à minha resposta. Considere editar sua pergunta para que mais gente possa tentar te ajudar.

Answer (score 1):

Não é necessáriamente a sua resposta, mas a maioria das aplicações mobile com html contido dentro da aplicação, interagem com regras de negócio através de serviços em [REST](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/REST). Não é nenhuma novidade esse conceito e ainda assim você consegue obedecer o [MVC](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/MVC).

Imagina que você tem um serviço que lista usuários na url (que retorna um [JSON](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON)): `http://domain.com/usuario/listar`

Com o uso da API do jQuery, você recuperaria os usuarios dessa forma:

```
$.getJSON("http://domain.com/usuario/listar", function(usuarios) {
        $.each(usuarios, function(indice, usuario) {
            $('body').append(indice + ": " +  usuario.nome + "<br>");
        });
    });
});
```

Agora se você já tem sua aplicação web e não quer portar parte dela para os dispositivos móveis, algumas pessoas apenas criam um executável por plataforma e chamam a aplicação web/site através de um iframe (no caso do android por exemplo, [WebView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html)¹)

> ¹ - A View that displays web pages. This class is the basis upon which you can roll your own web browser or simply display some online content within your Activity. It uses the WebKit rendering engine to display web pages and includes methods to navigate forward and backward through a history, zoom in and out, perform text searches and more

Comment: é uma alternativa, mas usar o iframe não seria uma boa prática já que pretendo criar um aplicativo escalável. mas já vejo uma luz.

Comment: Editei a resposta e coloqueia a citação do que é uma WebView. O adjetivo iFrame foi só para contextualizar um componente, não tem nenhuma relação com iFrame do html. O que é um aplicativo escalável para você ? Visto que o "client" seria o aplicativo e o "server" (onde fica seu negócio) já está altamente desaclopado de qualquer recurso.

Comment: Eu entendi agora, tinha entendio como iframe html. quando disse escalável pensei mas pelo lado $negócios. Grato.

Comment: Escalabilidade não está ligada a negócio$: http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escalabilidade